# Error(11,10): PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'CONSTRUCT'

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle10g

I am new to plsql i try to run the piece of code but it is giving error and not able to debug

```
create or replace type final as object ( ename1 varchar2(10), sal1 
NUMBER(7,2));--object 

create or replace type construct is table  of final; /*nested table of 
object type */

create or replace function returnmore (empno1 number) /*Function to 
return more*/
return construct 
AS
vemp construct:=construct();
vename varchar2(10);
vsal1 NUMBER(7,2);
begin

select ENAME,sal into vename,vsal1 from emp where empno=empno1;
vemp.extend;
vemp(1):=construct(vename,vsal1);
return vemp;
end;
```

But gives me an error

```
Function SYSTEM.RETURNMORE@loacaDB
Error(11,1): PL/SQL: Statement ignored
Error(11,10): PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'CONSTRUCT'
```

I am using oracle10gxe and sqldeveloper4.2

Answer (score 1):

You can prefer using non-preserved keyword such as `typ_emp` instead of `final` which's reserved.

```
SQL> create or replace type typ_emp as object ( ename1 varchar2(10), sal1 number(7,2));
SQL> create or replace type construct is table of typ_emp;
```

and you can convert your function as below :

```
create or replace function returnmore( empno1 emp.empno%type ) 
 return construct AS
  vemp   construct := construct();
  vename varchar2(10);
  vsal1  number(7, 2);
begin
  select ename, sal into vename, vsal1 from emp where empno = empno1;
  vemp.extend;
  vemp(1) := typ_emp(vename, vsal1);
  dbms_output.put_line(vemp(1).ename1);

  return vemp;
end;
/
```

or another way to handle the same operation :

```
SQL> create or replace function returnmore( empno1 emp.empno%type ) 
  return construct AS
  vemp   construct := construct();
  v_sql  varchar2(2000);
begin
  v_sql := 'select typ_emp(ename, sal) from emp where empno = :v_empno1';
  execute immediate v_sql bulk collect into vemp using empno1;
  dbms_output.put_line(vemp(1).ename1);

  return vemp;
end;
/
```

and test by invoking

```
SQL> set serveroutput on; 
SQL> declare
  result construct;
begin
  result := returnmore( 1 ); -- 1 is just an ordinary presumed value for empno 
end; 
/   --> this will return the employee name as printed.
```

P.S. Never ever use `SYSTEM` user for non-administrative purposes. May be extremely harmful for your database.

Comment: do we need to use Dynamic sql in this case for better performance or why

Comment: @Arun no, you don't need for performance, just another suggestion you can try to use.